# SharePoint 2010 Foundation Search result pages being combined when they are not the same in anyway

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, search-results

I have a content source and rules setup that enable my search to crawl the following type of URL's with parameters to a custom web part page.

```
http://hostname/sitepages/resources.aspx?groupID=All&IDnum=1
```

In my crawl log I am able to see that each of my items on this page (being generated from a List) are being crawled successfully.

For Example: 
If I have 3 resources in the resource List (list being read to generate Custom web part Resources Page at resources.aspx) :

```
http://hostname/sitepages/resources.aspx?groupID=All&IDnum=1

http://hostname/sitepages/resources.aspx?groupID=All&IDnum=2

http://hostname/sitepages/resources.aspx?groupID=All&IDnum=3
```

All show crawled successfully.

Custom Webpart page Description:
When this page (resources.aspx?groupID=All&IDnum=X) loads with a parameter for IDnum, the page loads ONLY that one resource as a link to the resource.  These Resources all have different "Titles" as the clickable href that is put on the page. (though some could include similar words like: Traval Voucher, Travel Agency) All this works great and the correct items load in the page when IDnum parameter is set. (IDnum is equal to the items List ID's).

The problem comes in when I do a search after the successful crawl, it seems Search (either CoreSearchResults, or the indexer itself?) are combining pages. Exammples

Page 1(`http://site/sitepages/resources.aspx?groupID=All&IDnum=122` :   Page contains one resource href with clickable Title:  Travel Voucher.

Page 2(`http://site/sitepages/resources.aspx?groupID=All&IDnum=123` :  Page contains one resource href with clickable Title:  Daily Vehicle Log.

Search for "Voucher", would return the two results above, it returns Page 1 as expected, as it has the word Voucher in it, and the result link takes you to the correct resource as the IDnum=122 parameter is correct, as expected.

BUT, it also returns the second result (Page 2), as well, and oddly it changes the Description of the result to Page 1's result description, but the link is still pointing to the resource on Page 2 (IDnum=123), if you click this result, the resource page showing only Daily Vehicle Log loads as expected.

Anyone ever see Search/CoreSearchResults/ or the SP indexer combine results like this???

Thanks for taking the time to read this, its not too easy to explain, so please feel free to ask for clarification / etc.

Comment: One other thing, if I were to do a search for say Daily, it finds no results as it seems to think that Daily Vehicle log, IS now, exactly the same thing as Travel Voucher. . . Just thought that might help.